# What bytes do I send to the MAX7221 to light an LED (in an led Matrix)?

Tags: led, spi, digital

*Datasheets*

- LED Matrix (p2): https://www.circuitspecialists.com/products/pdf/M105057CHR1.pdf
- MAX7221: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/COM-09622-MAX7219-MAX7221.pdf

*Convention*

- (Row, Col) Designates an LED at a particular row and column, following the convention set by the datasheet
- {Anode, Cathode} Designates a anode/cathode pair to light an LED in the array
- Assume that I've connected:
  SEG_DP to pin 13
  SEG_A to 3
  SEG_B to 11
  SEG_C to 10
  SEG_D to 6
  DIG_0 to 9
  DIG_1 to 14
  ...
  DIG_6 to 2

Question:
Suppose I'm interested in lighting (1,1). By the convention, I would have to source current to pin 13 and sink current from pin 9. What two bytes should I send to the MAX7221 to achieve this?

My Attempt:
I think it should be 0x01 and 0x80 (0000|0001|1000|0000) with MSB (D15 as it is referred to in the datasheet for MAX7221) on the far left. Code I tried using is below as an image. I checked the signals with a logic analyzer and verified that the SPI protocol was followed (I forgot to take a screenshot but I will provide one when I get a chance). The LED array did not behave as I had anticipated. All LEDs in the matrix were lit!

[image: Program]

Comment: What about using a library? http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LEDMatrix has a few. Even if you prefer to write your own code you should be able to find a few hints there.

Comment: Add a delay after setting the SS low. Also specify try adding `PI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);` and/or `SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);`

Comment: can you explain the clock divider function? For reference, the MAX runs at 10Mhz and the MCU that I'm using (Arduino Uno) runs at 16Mhz